# variables of nullable type - do they take up space when set to null?

Tags: c#, nullable

Suppose I have an `int` variable defined in a C# program. Regardless of the value stored, it is always going to take 32 bits of memory. How do nullable types behave in this regard? If an `int?` variable is set to `null`, will it still occupy 32 bits of space?

Comment: Is you question about `int` or `Nullable<T>`?

Answer (score 3):

If the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e) is anything to go by, `Nullable<T>` always takes up the size of `T` + the size of a `bool` indicating if `T` is valid or not. So in your case it would take `4` + `1` (`bool` isn't bitpacked, so it takes a full byte) = `5` bytes. This doesn't include any runtime-specific padding or optimizations.